# Concise collectFirst over nested lists in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm writing a simple interpreter in Scala.

This interpreter stores what is essentially a `List[List[(Symbol, Value)]]` environment:

```
case class Env(frames: List[Frame]) {
   def lookup(s: LSymbol): Option[Value] = ??? // help
}
case class Frame(associations: List[(LSymbol, Value)]){
 def find(s: LSymbol): Option[Value] = {
   this.associations.collectFirst {case (s1, v) if s1 == s => v}
 }
}
```

I'd essentially like to search each frame for a matching symbol in turn. Although it's simple enough to write a small tail recursive search function for this, it feels like something which could be done more efficiently and generally and with a `collectFirst` one-liner, like so:

```
def lookup(s: LSymbol): Option[Value] = 
 this.frames.collectFirst{
  case frame if frame.find(s).nonEmpty => frame.find(s).get
 }
```

However, this is redundantly doing work in the second `frame.find(s)`. Is there a way to somehow do this lookup concisely in a non-wasteful way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a special purpose extractor to extract `frame.find(s)` value. This way you will also get rid of `nonEmpty` / `get` calls, because pattern matching already does that for you:

```
def lookup(s: LSymbol): Option[Value] = {
  object FindS {
    def unapply(frame: Frame): Option[Value] = frame.find(s)
  }
  this.frames.collectFirst {
    case FindS(value) => value
  }
}
```

If you do something like this often, you might even want to define a helper class to make extractor construction easier:

```
class Extractor[T, X](f: T => Option[X]) {
  def unapply(arg: T): Option[X] = f(arg)
}

def lookup(s: LSymbol): Option[Value] = {
  object FindS extends Extractor((frame: Frame) => frame.find(s))
  this.frames.collectFirst {
    case FindS(value) => value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `view` should make the evaluation lazy and then you can use `map` and `filter` like this:

```
def lookup(s: LSymbol): Option[Value] =
  this.frames.view.map(_.find(s)).filter(_.nonEmpty).head
```

This is a one-liner, but perhaps not as concise as you might like...